# Jquery animate works in console, but not in script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been beating my head against this all day.  I'm writing this little slider/image rotating script and I cannot get it to change these elements.  I can animate the images from the console with `$('.slide:nth-child(1)').animate({display: 'block'});`, but nothing from the script.

html

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="/_site/images/interior-decor.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="/_site/images/Showhome-Living-Room.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="/_site/images/SL-Master-bedroom-1.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var sl = {} || [];
sl.imgs = $('.slide');
sl.cnt = 1;
sl.wait = 6000;
sl.num = sl.imgs.length;  //count length of .slide divs
//hide all but first image
$('.slide:nth-child(n + 2)').css('display', 'none');
//
sl.func = function() {
    var prev = sl.cnt;
    sl.cnt++;
    var next;
    if (sl.cnt > (sl.num)) {
       sl.cnt = 1;
       next = 1;
    }
    else {next = sl.cnt;}

    $('.slide:nth-child(' + next + ')').animate({display: 'block'});
    $('.slide:nth-child(' + prev + ')').animate({display: 'none'});
    console.log('Previous: '+prev+'  Next: '+next);
};
window.setInterval(function() {
    sl.func()
}, sl.wait);
```

The script consoles out `Previous: 1  Next: 2` and so forth every six seconds, but nothing changes.

Comment: Would suggest you put together a fiddle that shows the issue.

Comment: Not sure that you can animate display poperty....but you could do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/pn8xv7de/

Comment: It animates from the console.  I'll look at your fiddle.

Comment: @TDave00, no, it doesn't. It just logs previous and next slide... Animation, it self, from display block to none, and vice versa - doesn't work....

Comment: Ok...maybe what I remembered was it animated width.  I know I did that from the console and the image animated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot animate `display` property. You can animate `opacity` or `max-height` instead:

```
$('.slide:nth-child(' + next + ')').animate({opacity: 1})
$('.slide:nth-child(' + prev + ')').animate({opacity: 0});
```

Comment: Thanks.  and Thanks @nevermind for the fiddle.  Got me going in the right direction.  animate works with width and height.  1 more bug to fix and it's good.